# Eventbrite API list events 403

Tags: api, http, events, request, eventbrite

I'm trying to fetch events base on time from Eventbrite API with the following command from the [docs](https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/by-date)

```
 curl -X GET https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search?date_modified.range_start=2018-01-01T00:00:01Z -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY_API_TOKEN'
```

However, it returns me 403 with the following HTML in response body:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Whoops!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="whoops_wrapper">
        <img id="logo" src="https://cdn.evbstatic.com/s3-s3/static/images/django/logos/eb_home_stroke-trans.png" width="154" />
        <h1>
            This page is <br />currently unavailable.
        </h1>
        <p>
            The Team is currently working to return you to the service as quickly as possible.<br />
            If you need to reach us immediately, please <a href='https://www.eventbrite.com/support/contact-us'>contact us</a>.
        </p>
        <p>
            We'll keep you updated on <a href='https://www.twitter.com/eventbrite'>Twitter</a>.<br />
            <a href='https://www.eventbritestatus.com/'>Eventbrite Status Page</a>
        </p>
        <p><font size="-2">Response code: 403</font></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It use to work fine before and now it like this for a couple days. I tried to create a new API Token with no success. Calling other endpoints from the API seams working fine. I also didn't hit the rate limit. Any ideas what it could be or things to try?

Answer (score 2):

According to the linked [Google Group Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eventbrite-api/-E0MG7THMsc)

> Thank you for your patience. We recently made some changes to our APIs in an effort to improve platform functionality and performance. Some of these adjustments necessitated the unforeseen and immediate deprecation of one of our public Event Search APIs `events/search` endpoint.
>
> Since this change was made, the team has been working hard on potential solutions for providing access to our event feed for API users that are not part of our official distribution partner program. We wanted to reach out to acknowledge the frustration you’re feeling and let you know that we will update you with more details over the coming week as we determine the viability of a potential replacement solution.
>
> Regards,
>
> Eventbrite.

So it looks like they've discontinued search from the public API.

Update: The Search API has been discontinued as of December 12 [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eventbrite-api/FT2MsDswdrA)

Comment: Update: Appears to be working again as of 30 October 2019

Answer (score 0):

Just came across [official Google Support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eventbrite-api/-E0MG7THMsc). Seams like internal Eventbrite issue. :(

Comment: Yeah, it's been like that for 3 days.

Comment: Ugh, I can believe Eventbrite team can not fix it in a timely manner.